# transitionend event not firing when there's no transition

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/jqs4yy0p/

JS

```
$('div').addClass('switch').on('transitionend', function(e){
    alert('end');
});
```

CSS

```
div {
    background-color: red;    
    /*transition: background-color 1s;    */
}

div.switch{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

if you uncomment the transition property it works, but without it no event is being fired!!

So if I make a slider thing, and want to preload next image after the transition effect completes I have to rely on the fact that there is a transition effect in the css. if there isn't the whole thing will break.

Doesn't this make transitions useless because you still have to mix them with javascript code in order to control them?

Comment: Why would it fire if you have no transition? You can always make the transition time so short that it is almost invisible to trigger the event

Comment: But how else would `transition effect completes` if there's no transition????

Comment: Quoting MDN: `The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed`... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: Why does this make transition useless? It's used for animation, the part where you want to do something when the transition ends is using js. Please edit the question to pin point the issue you are having

Comment: ok but the problem is that transitions are supposed to be separated from javascript. If my javascript code depends on the presence of a transitions that is not true anymore

Comment: You are writing javascript that says "If there is a transition, do this when it ends". If that is not the use case for your function then use a different event..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get things straight - the event `transitionend` (or any related javascript) is in no way needed to use or control CSS transitions/animations (which makes them completely independent, although, as a sidenote, CSS transitions/animations can be triggered using js, which can again sometimes be a very useful addition to the basic possibilities offered by the CSS interface).

Listening in on `transitionend` events can serve as a great tool when you are adding javascript functionality to your page as it makes your javascript aware of transition events triggered by the CSS.
E.g.: *"I want to execute some javascript, but if there is a transition (triggered by the CSS), i want to wait for it to finish first."*

Using something like

```
$('div').css('transitionDuration') !== '0s'
```

you can check if your object has a transition set.

[**QUICK DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/jqs4yy0p/2/) (based on your jsfiddel)

And to get back to your "slider thing" example ... just swapping the images with js (will work just fine, already without the smooth transition effect) and adding CSS transitions for a reacher UX. Living the transitions out of the equation will probably effect the functionality less than living out some other parts of the CSS (position,width,height,opacity...).

Maybe I am failing to see your question here ... but IMHO the existence of events/listeners that give you the possibility to detect (or manipulate) CSS transitions/animations does in no way make these useless or redundant. To me it sounds similar to saying CSS pseudo elements are redundant as you can just add additional elements to your markup ... of course you can do it either way ... but I just like to keep my content (html), styling (CSS) and logic (JS) layers separate (but in the end it comes down to the specific problem at hand and of course to your personal preferences).

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, you can use: `element.computedStyleMap().get("transition-duration").value > 0` for your element.